# Resetting counter-variables over time

Tags: python, pandas

I have data similar to this dataset.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([])
data["time"] = range(20)
data["id"] = [1]*8 + [2]*12
data["x"] = [0, .53, 1.06, 1.59, 2.12, 2.65, .2, .73, .4, 1, 1.6, 2.2, 2.8, 3.4, .2, .8, 1.4, 2, 2.6, 3]
data["x_desiderated"] = [0, .53, 1.06, 1.59, 2.12, 2.65, 3.18, 3.71, .4, 1, 1.6, 2.2, 2.8, 3.4, 4, 4.6, 5.2, 5.8, 6.4, 7]

   time id   x    x_desiderated
0   0   1   0.00    0.00
1   1   1   0.53    0.53
2   2   1   1.06    1.06
3   3   1   1.59    1.59
4   4   1   2.12    2.12
5   5   1   2.65    2.65
6   6   1   0.20    3.18
7   7   1   0.73    3.71
8   8   2   0.40    0.40
9   9   2   1.00    1.00
10  10  2   1.60    1.60
11  11  2   2.20    2.20
12  12  2   2.80    2.80
13  13  2   3.40    3.40
14  14  2   0.20    4.00
15  15  2   0.80    4.60
16  16  2   1.40    5.20
17  17  2   2.00    5.80
18  18  2   2.60    6.40
19  19  2   3.00    7.00
```

The problem is that x should increases over time by a delta almost constant for each id. In this toy example x should increases by .53 for id = 1 and .6 for id = 2. 
I have a casual reset at some point instead. 
I'd like to create an new x variable in which i can simulate a normal behaviour of x.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried a for loop and if statements but it would be to slow I suppose

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
delta = 0.5
data["x_delta"] = data["id"] * delta
# or data["x_delta"] = list_with_delta_vallues
data["new_x"] = data["x"] + data["x_delta"]
```